# Current feedback amplifier

Tags: current, amplifier, feedback, photodiode, transimpedance

I was wondering whether is it ok to connect a current feedback amplifier (CFA) after the TIA stage to obtain high swing and large bandwidth. I am not sure how to connect the CFA after the TIA stage.

Comment: The TIA has relatively low output impedance. So comply with the Vin CM limits

Comment: https://www.ovationhifidelity.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/An-Introduction-to-CFA-Amplifiers-for-Audio.pdf

Comment: I think,, there is no fundamental difference between a transimpedance amplifier (TIA)  and a CFA. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LvW You are wrong; a CFA is a type of op amp with a low-impedance inverting input, which has a much higher bandwidth than conventional op amps. The noninverting input is still high-impedance, meaning it amplifies a voltage, but its feedback is in the form of a current.

Comment: Your question has either got nothing to do with the TIA and everything to do with "how do I design using a CFA" OR, it's got everything to do with TIA and how to design using them.

Comment: @Hearth, I know that the CFA has two different inputs (it is the heart of a CCII). But then, what is the TIA? It is not an OTA and not a NORTON amp, but...?

Comment: @LvW Think of a photodiode amplifier (using the photodiode in photoconductive mode, anyway), for instance. Input signal is a current, output is a voltage. It's a circuit you can make with a conventional op amp, not a special type of amplifier.

Comment: So - do you think that it is a classical voltage opamp that is wired (and used) as current-to-voltage converter? I very well remember the first days/weeks/month after the CFA was invented - and some companies were using the term "TIA" for the unit we today call CFA.

Comment: Here is an example (excerpt from the data sheet): The LTC®6561 is a low-noise four-channel, transimpedance amplifier (TIA)with 220MHz bandwidth. .....
The amplifier features 74kΩ transimpedance gain.....